# How to apply changes to slatejs react editor without triggering onChange?

Tags: reactjs, slate.js

How can you apply changes to slatejs react editor without triggering onChange?

I remember reading in slatejs docs that there was some method you could call to apply changes to the editor without triggering the onChange method of the editor.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @SethHays no, I haven't